# Wallet Recovery

Tags: private-key, wallet-recovery

In 2013 I started downloading BitcoinQT and the blockchain thinking I was going to mine. I never even finished the download and eventually deleted it from the computer. I still have my wallet ID and passkey but never created a 12 phrase seed.

I have Bitcoin in this wallet but cannot seem to access it. My research thus far indicates I have to download BitcoinCore and the entire 100GB blockchain just to restore the wallet. Even if I do this, won't I still experience the same issue of having to maintain the blockchain on a computer in order to use the wallet?
 Surely there must be a simpler wallet? I haven't had any luck importing it into Electrum (watching/receiving only) or Exodus. I'm running a Mac.

Your wisdom is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to recover anything from a bitcoin address you must have at least one of the following:

- the private key
- the WIF (wallet import format)
- the phrase seed

For spending the money of an address you must have the private key wich is reversably obtainable from the WIF or generated from a phrase seed. If you don't have any of these you probably lost your money